# Appeal regarding the closure of a question

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions, reopen-request

I asked a question and it was closed as being primarily opinion based. I frankly don't see how and am willing to listen to anyone who is willing to explain how a question about latency in RAM is opinion based. I did not ask for a brand to choose from, I did not ask for opinions on whether my RAM was sufficient. **I asked if the higher latency offered a gain that was justified by the substantially higher price**. There was an answer that was accepted and it was unbiased. The question was closed afterward. Please clarify. 
[When buying RAM on a budget, do I choose higher capacity or lower latency?](https://superuser.com/questions/774395/buying-ram-on-a-budget-higher-capacity-or-lower-latency)?

PS : Just because I use 4GB RAM does not make specific as a majority of laptops today are shipped with this amount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question sounds reasonable. It's not asking for a specific hardware recommendation, but rather about general advice when you're in the market for new memory.

I reopened it.

Comment: Thank you for your support @slhck and also for help with editing the question.

Answer (score -1):

Some of the problem the question caused a differance in approaches to the question based on parts of the whole question.
The question ended up with people quibbling over the different aspects of a complex question.

For future referance limiting your question to single things, could keep the question from being observed 2 different ways, 3 If you account for the price thing added.
Does ram CAS RAS refresh rates make that much speed differance. A) in ram speed B) in overall computer speed.
Is much more memory beneficial to my needs assuming these programs.
Is low latency memory worth the extra money (opinion)

It was the Duality of the question.  "More memory is better , because the way the system utalises it."  "Faster memory is faster, the value of such to be determined by the buyer."

I thought the question was ok, it wasn't until it was answered that you could see the train wreck it created. I also thought that the answers did not deserve to be downvoted.  Overall you did get what you came for.

If at any time you could break your question into single items, facting out one item would endure time, be more useful for others, and would not be observed different ways.

Knowing some data on how timing and speed settings effects ram, then knowing if much more ram is useful to your scenario, would have still given you enough data to decide.

Comment: Sorry but some questions inherently require substantial context and are next to impossible to break down to "single things". I am with you that it's ideal - yet **complex questions with multiple possible answers shouldn't be reason to close them**. The onus to provide concise answers shouldn't be on the asker - it should be on the answerer! Can't answer the question - pass on it, don't close it.